# objective-c navbar back button (created in storyboard) not hiding in detail view controller

Tags: objective-c, hide, back-button, master-detail

I created the interface of my app using storyboard. The layout is as follows:
NavigationController -> MasterViewController -> TabViewController -> DetailViewControllers.

I would like the first two DetailViewControllers to have a back button that can be hidden/shown at various times based on the user's progress through the app.

I have searched, found, and tried many "solutions." With all, the app compiles correctly, but not one of them will hide the back button (which takes the user back to the tableview in the MasterViewController).

"Solutions" I have tried:

In MasterViewController's viewDidLoad:

```
[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES animated:YES];
UIBarButtonItem* backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Start" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(initializeStuff)];    
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
```

.....or.....

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

.....or.....

```
UINavigationBar *navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc]init];
UINavigationItem *navigationItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc]init];
UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init]; 
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Test" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(backButtonTapped)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = addButton;
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.enabled=NO;
[navBar pushNavigationItem:navigationItem animated:NO];
```

In MasterViewController's viewWillAppear and in first DetailViewController's initWithNibName:

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

In MasterViewController's viewDidAppear:

```
[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES animated:YES];
```

.....or.....

```
_detailViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;
```

In first DetailViewController's viewDidLoad and in viewWillAppear and in viewDidAppear:

```
[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES animated:YES];
UIBarButtonItem* backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Start" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(initializeStuff)];
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;
```

I appreciate the wisdom on this board and look forward to any help you might be able to offer.  :)

Comment: While waiting for a suggestion, I started playing with other options.  I have now removed my back button from the navigation item of my MasterViewController and have added a Bar Button Item to the toolbar in the view of the DetailViewController which pops back to the tableview of the MasterViewController when pressed.  This button is very easy to enable/disable at the appropriate times in DetailViewController.  It seems to do exactly what I was trying to accomplish.  :)